# axios multipart/form-data - get estimated compilation time

Tags: javascript, http, axios, multipartform-data

Is there a way to get estimated compilation time for sending files(`'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`) via axios or other http lib?
for example-

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file) //file=event.target.files[0]
const config = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}
return post(url, formData, config); //axios post
```

For very large files I want to display a timer for the user.
I can use other libs so axios is optional.
I can access the file size - `file.size` and access the downlink -`navigator.connection.downlink` but I don't know the right calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to monitor the progress of sending XMLHttpRequest

See the [docs on mdn here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total * 100;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}
```

Also axios (see [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)) itself has a config parameter to update the UI on progress:

```
onUploadProgress: function( progressEvent ) {
        this.uploadPercentage = parseInt( Math.round( ( progressEvent.loaded * 100 ) / progressEvent.total ) );
      }.bind(this)
```

Comment: Yes but I want to display estimated time, not percentComplete, both this function return percent.